# Is it possible to merge by exporting and importing changesets in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

My team is currently in the situation that half the team is in Germany and the other half in the Netherlands.

We're using Mercurial as source control. The problem is that now that we are split up, because the way the company network works, it is not possible to connect our repositories together to do any pushing or pulling between them.

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow export a bunch of changesets, send it by mail or w/e and then import them on the other side?

I'm really new to Mercurial and distributed source control (previously I only worked with SVN really). But I understand that one of the differences is that it merges by reapplying all the changes instead of just looking at the difference between latest versions. That's why I thought that this might be possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a cloud service like BitBucket.  That way, your "central" repository can be totally private and in the cloud, and it doesn't matter where anyone is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. See http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#email

**Edit:** Use `-b/--bundle` to send multiple changesets as a bundle.

Comment: Hmm, as I understand it will sent an email per changeset. Isn't it possible to get it in one mail?